# Transferring a system built in php(with cakephp) to the other server

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, cakephp

I want to transfer a system to the other server with the deterioration of the server that a certain system works.

After transferring a program file and a database to a new server, an error occurs.

■Error contents

---

Warning (2): pg_query() [function.pg-query]:

Query failed: ERROR:  An input sentence structure of model integer is invalid: "\x3234"
LINE 1: ...Aro0"."model" = 'User' AND "Aro0"."foreign_key" = '\x3234'  ...
                                                             ^ [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_postgres.php, line 148]

※Original Message(in japanese) : Query failed: ERROR:  型integerの入力構文が無効です: "\x37"

---

For environment

(former)

- PHP: 5.2.13
- CakePHP: 1.2.7
- Apache:  2.2.15
- Postgre: 8.4.4-1

(newly)

- PHP: 5.5.15
- CakePHP: 1.2.7
- Apache:  2.4.10
- Postgre: 9.2.9.1

I copied a program file from an old server after installation of PHP and Apache and PostgreSQL.

※I changed the connection server to the new server in database.php

※I describe php.ini, httpd.conf to become the setting same as an old server

Login screen (index.php) coming to be displayed, 
and inputting ID and a password, and running login processing, the errors occurred.

The real error is ""foreign_key" = '\x3234'" part 
that only numerical value guesses character string called"'\x3234'" right in foreign_key.
Only the number to 2 figures is really registered with the item equal to foreign_key even if I confirm a database.

Foreign_key which the login user has is "24",
but seems to be treated in one of login processing as "'\x3234'".

After doing it I tryed to login in other login users,

9　⇒　'\x39'

7　⇒　'\x37'

23　⇒　'\x3233'

24　⇒　'\x3234'

The left is foreign_key, and the right is really used by SQL.
A head has "\x3", and there seems to be "3" before the second column when there are two columns.

Is there any differents for settings of PHP/CAKEPHP/APACHE/POSTGRESQL ?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stack overflow. Please read the formatting guidance and use preview when you post. Your post is very hard to read because of the weird bullets and lack of markdown formatting.

Comment: Also, if you're going to translate error messages to English, please provide the originals too. It's often more useful to look them up in the translation files than to have a translation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.I tried to edit my post with using markdown and add original error message(in Japanese).

Comment: Check the collation of the DB and the connection? Looks like an encoding issue.

Comment: Tanks burzum. I checked the collation and encoding.The collation is "Japanese_Japan.932" and encoding is "UTF8". It's same as the settings of old server's DB.